# How to fix insert error during inserting a list into sqlite db

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I have a simple code, which should supply me with a prices and descriptions from my wish list located on Amazon. Unfortunately during the execution I have an error related to my insert statement.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sqlite3
import movie

#Getting my wishlist html
page = requests.get("some_url").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
soupd = soup.div


#Looking for item price  and descriptions

prices =[]
for price_container in soupd.find_all('span',class_='a-price'):
    price = price_container.span.text
    prices.append(price)

descriptions=[]
for description_container in soupd.find_all('h3',class_='a-size-base'):
    description = description_container.a.text
    descriptions.append(description)



conn = sqlite3.connect('movie_prices.db')
c = conn.cursor()

print(len(descriptions))
print(len(prices))

c.executemany('INSERT INTO movies (price,title) VALUES (?, ?)', prices,descriptions)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The error message is as below:

c.executemany('INSERT INTO movies (price,title) VALUES (?, ?)', prices,descriptions)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to zip your two lists

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO movies (price,title) VALUES (?, ?)', zip(prices,descriptions))
```

The arguments need to be passed as pairs, which zip will give you

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. This was exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: No worries, you can mark the answer as the correct one if you like

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) shows that parentheses should be used to pass multiple parameters :

```py
c.executemany('INSERT INTO movies (price,title) VALUES (?, ?)', (prices,descriptions,))
```

Also use `execute()` for a single query